# DatePicker giving NullPointerException when setting Date

Tags: android, datepicker, nullpointerexception, arabic

I changed the locale of Android Emulator to Arabic to test the Arabic version of my application. The date picker appears as shown below,

[image: Arabic DatePicker]

Although the DatePicker was working perfectly in the English version of my application, now t is giving me the following error.

```
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at org.digitalhealthagency.elaj.gui.AppointmentReservationActivity$DoctorWorkingDaysTask.access$2(AppointmentReservationActivity.java:927)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at org.digitalhealthagency.elaj.gui.AppointmentReservationActivity$5.onDateSet(AppointmentReservationActivity.java:454)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:148)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onStop(DatePickerDialog.java:155)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:326)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:302)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:170)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-08 11:13:44.544: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Met
hod)
```

Am I missing something I should be doing for the Arabic version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this problem appeared when I tested on an Android 4.1 emulator. The `DatePickerDialog` looks quite different and has one button instead of two, but my code is working normally on Android 4.0.3 emulators and below.

Posted another question here [Android: Android 4.1 Emulator Invoking onDateSet Twice from DatePicker Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383592/android-android-4-1-emulator-invoking-ondateset-twice-from-datepicker-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything specific to Arabic.  In the absence of any code, the best I can do is suggest some debugging techniques.

If you look at the code on line 927 of AppointmentReservationActivity.java, I suspect whatever you're accessing a method/field of will give it away.

If you don't see it right away, try setting a breakpoint on that line and check your variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I found out that the problem is that my onDateSet listener is called twice, could you please check this new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383592/android-android-4-1-emulator-invoking-ondateset-twice-from-datepicker-dialog