# onDateSet does not get called from DatePickerDialog on tablet

Tags: java, android, tabs, galaxy, datepickerdialog

I am using a DatePickerDialog to prompt the user for a date. It works fine in the simulator and on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, but onDateSet does not get called on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

I noticed, that the dialog is bigger and shows a calendar besides the normal spin view. Can that be the problem?

Here is some code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import com.cbit.gtbetapp.R;
import com.cbit.gtbetapp.gui.racedata.MeetingDataActivity;
import com.cbit.gtbetapp.gui.racedata.MeetingListFragment;
import com.cbit.gtbetapp.logic.Utility;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    protected Date date = null;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Utility.getToday();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        date = c.getTime();

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day) {
            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
                setTitle(getString(R.string.date_picker_title));
            }
        };
        dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.date_picker_title));

        dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                getString(android.R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MeetingDataActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        intent.putExtra(MeetingListFragment.EXTRA_DATE, date.getTime());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
        dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                getString(R.string.button_cancel),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return dialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.clear();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        date = c.getTime();
    }
}
```

What could cause this? A bug in the tablet? Am I missing something? Can anyone think of a workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that it's working at all. The `onDateSet()` gets called when the *default* `onClick` behavior is executed, but since you're completely setting new buttons you're getting rid of the original behavior. You can [check the code out](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r2.1/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java#DatePickerDialog.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.Context%2Cint%2Candroid.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29). Why are you not starting your activity in the `onDateSet()`? If what you want is to set the text, then you can get each button instead of setting them (`getButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE)`).

Also, beware that there's a new bug in Jelly Bean where the `onDateSet` will get called twice, will get called even if you press back AND they also removed the default Cancel button. Go figure.

Comment: Here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444238/jelly-bean-datepickerdialog-is-there-a-way-to-cancel/11493752#11493752) that works around the issue I mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that great alternative! It works perfectly!