# TimepickerDialog : onTimeSet never called on samsung devices with touchwiz

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-timepicker

I have 2 Edittext on which i pop a timepickerdialog when touched :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initTimePicker();
    }

    private void initTimePicker()
    {
        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        final int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        final EditText deplacementD = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText deplacementF = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        deplacementD.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        deplacementF.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        // Attachement du timepicker
        deplacementD.setOnTouchListener(getTimePicker(hour, minute, "Start"));
        deplacementF.setOnTouchListener(getTimePicker(hour, minute,  "End"));

    }

    private OnTouchListener getTimePicker(final int heure, final int minute, final String titre)
    {
        return new OnTouchListener() {

            private boolean validated = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                final EditText editTouched = (EditText) v;

                Log.d("Timepicker", "On Touch event");
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    Log.d("Timepicker", "Motion event UP");

                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

                    Log.d("Timepicker", "New timepickerdialog instance");
                    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(editTouched.getContext(),
                            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                                {
                                    Log.d("Timepicker", "OnTimeSet called");
                                    if (validated)
                                        editTouched.setText(String
                                                .format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
                                }

                            }, 00, 00, true);// Yes 24 hour time

                    Log.d("Timepicker", "Timepicker title set");
                    mTimePicker.setTitle(titre);

                    mTimePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    Log.d("Timepicker", "Cancel Clicked");
                                    validated = false;
                                }
                            });

                    mTimePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                            getString(android.R.string.ok),
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                                {
                                    Log.d("Timepicker", "Ok called");
                                    validated = true;
                                }
                            });
                    Log.d("Timepicker", "Timepicker show()");
                    mTimePicker.show();
                    Log.d("Timepicker", "out of getTimePicker return true");
                    return true;
                }
                Log.d("Timepicker", "out of getTimePicker return false");
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

On stock android devices (nexus s,4,5) everything work perfectly. The timepickerdialog appear and the edittext is set when i click the positive button.

On contrary , with Samsung devices (S4 4.4.2 and Note II 4.3) the dialog appears but `onTimeSet` is never called. No error in the logcat though.

Here a the result of the log message put in getTimepicker() :

On nexus Devices :

```
05-26 09:45:51.850: D/Timepicker(3219): Attaching timepicker
05-26 09:45:51.850: D/Timepicker(3219): Inside getTimePicker()
05-26 09:45:58.007: D/Timepicker(3219): On Touch event
05-26 09:45:58.007: D/Timepicker(3219): out of getTimePicker return false
05-26 09:45:58.027: D/Timepicker(3219): On Touch event
05-26 09:45:58.027: D/Timepicker(3219): out of getTimePicker return false
05-26 09:45:58.077: D/Timepicker(3219): On Touch event
05-26 09:45:58.077: D/Timepicker(3219): Motion event UP
05-26 09:45:58.077: D/Timepicker(3219): New timepickerdialog instance
05-26 09:45:58.167: D/Timepicker(3219): Timepicker title set
05-26 09:45:58.177: D/Timepicker(3219): Timepicker show()
05-26 09:45:58.187: D/Timepicker(3219): out of getTimePicker return true
05-26 09:46:05.745: D/Timepicker(3219): Ok called
05-26 09:46:05.745: D/Timepicker(3219): OnTimeSet called
```

`OnTimeSet()` is called just after i have clicked the OK button.

On contrary on Samsung devices :

```
05-26 09:47:59.500: D/Timepicker(12897): Attaching timepicker
05-26 09:47:59.500: D/Timepicker(12897): Inside getTimePicker()
05-26 09:48:01.105: D/Timepicker(12897): On Touch event
05-26 09:48:01.105: D/Timepicker(12897): out of getTimePicker return false
05-26 09:48:01.125: D/Timepicker(12897): On Touch event
05-26 09:48:01.125: D/Timepicker(12897): out of getTimePicker return false
05-26 09:48:01.160: D/Timepicker(12897): On Touch event
05-26 09:48:01.160: D/Timepicker(12897): out of getTimePicker return false
05-26 09:48:01.190: D/Timepicker(12897): On Touch event
05-26 09:48:01.190: D/Timepicker(12897): Motion event UP
05-26 09:48:01.190: D/Timepicker(12897): New timepickerdialog instance
05-26 09:48:01.230: D/Timepicker(12897): Timepicker title set
05-26 09:48:01.230: D/Timepicker(12897): Timepicker show()
05-26 09:48:01.245: D/Timepicker(12897): out of getTimePicker return true
05-26 09:48:04.700: D/Timepicker(12897): Ok called
```

On timeset is never called

What should i do to make my code compliant with samsung devices ?

Comment: It sound weird and unreasonable.. In samsung device, What is happening when you press on the text box? You can add logs to your code and show the code with results with the output?

Comment: Added some log inside getTimePicker. As you can see , the result is the same except for the call of OnTimeSet().

Comment: `myTextView` is a `EditText` or a `TextView`?

Comment: It is an EditText. Corrected my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem:

onTimeSet was called from my nexus VDM but not from Samsung GS3. Both have android 4.3.
[This answer helped me to work through the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165328/timepickerdialog-ontimesetlistener-not-called)

Comment: Using an AlertDialog with a timepicker as view worked !

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a little while I get it to work, I have a Samsung Galaxy S2, and `onTimeSet` is getting called. What I did what the following.

- You have declared `getTimePicker` as a class member and initialized in the same place, I've declared the `Listener`, but initialize it in `onCreate`:

  ```
  private OnTouchListener myListener;
  ```

And then inside `onCreate`:

```
final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed1);
final EditText myEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed2);

myListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    private Boolean validated;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        final EditText editTouched = (EditText) v;

        Log.d("Timepicker", "On Touch event");
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.d("Timepicker", "Motion event UP");

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

            Log.d("Timepicker", "New timepickerdialog instance");
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(editTouched.getContext(),
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
                        {
                            Log.d("Timepicker", "OnTimeSet called");
                            if (validated)
                                editTouched.setText(String
                                        .format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
                        }

                    }, 00, 00, true);// Yes 24 hour time

            Log.d("Timepicker", "Timepicker title set");
            mTimePicker.setTitle("TITLE");

            mTimePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "ANULAR",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            Log.d("Timepicker", "Cancel Clicked");
                            validated = false;
                        }
                    });

            mTimePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                    getString(android.R.string.ok),
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            Log.d("Timepicker", "Ok called");
                            validated = true;
                        }
                    });
            Log.d("Timepicker", "Timepicker show()");
            mTimePicker.show();
            Log.d("Timepicker", "out of getTimePicker return true");
            return true;
        }
        Log.d("Timepicker", "out of getTimePicker return false");
        return false;
    }
};

myEditText.setOnTouchListener(myListener);
myEditText2.setOnTouchListener(myListener);
```

Here is the result:

[image: Logcat]

Hope it help you.

Comment: You removed the getTimepicker() method and put the code in setOnTouchListener right ? I have 6 EditText which need the same timepicker , so i cleary can't do that. Btw , doing this don"t change anything on Galaxy note II.

Comment: @grunk I've tested with two editText, check my answer

Comment: Thanks , but not working on GN2 with android 4.3 stock samsung rom. The target of timepicker is the edittext which trigger it , not an other textView

Comment: @grunk, Edited, now it does what you want. Have you tried use a onClick Listener instead of an onTouch? Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: What version of Android are you running on your device ? Your code does not trigger OnTimeSet() on my GN2 nor on GS4. I have updated my original question , can you try the code i have put in it ?

Comment: @grunk I've proved and it works perfectly. I have Android 4.4 with CyanogenMod

Comment: Have you tried with an onClickListener?, maybe that work

Comment: Tried with onClick but result is the same

Comment: No idea what is happening then. Sorry