# TimePickerFragment not calling onTimeSet mothod on all android devices

Tags: java, android, timepicker, android-timepicker

I am implementing time picker dialog in my android app. I want to set 3 buttons to that dialog, "Set", "Clear", "Cancel".

I am using TimePickerFragment, i have done the code for this but its not working on all android devices correctly, on some devices its work perfect, but on some device its not.

**I am using following code:-**

```
    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        OnTimeSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                getActivity(), this, hour, min, true);
        timePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.done1),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isTimeSet = true;
                        System.out.println("only true");
                    }
                });

        timePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.cancle),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isTimeSet = false;
                        System.out.println("only false");
                        //tvTime1.setText(userAlarmStartTime);
                    }
                });

        timePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,
                getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.clear),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        isTimeSet = false;
                        System.out.println("only neutral");
                        tvTime1.setText("");
                    }
                });
        return timePickerDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//          System.out.println("value in time set:- " + isTimeSet);
        if (isTimeSet) {
            String userAlarmStartTime;
            if (minute < 10) {
                userAlarmStartTime = hourOfDay + ":0" + minute;
            } else {
                userAlarmStartTime = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            }
            tvTime1.setText(userAlarmStartTime);
        }

    }
}
```

**and for calling this i am using following code:-**

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

when i debug my code on some devices its not calling `onTimeSet()` method, but on some devices its calling that method.

i have searched lot on about this, but i couldn't find anything that will help me to solve problem.

anyone can please tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165328/timepickerdialog-ontimesetlistener-not-called