# Why Is TimePicker Dialog Blank On Samsung Marshmallow 6.0.1?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-timepicker

On Lollipop 5.1.1 on a Nexus 4, and on Marshmallow 6.0.1 on the emulator, the `TimePickerDialog` comes up in my application looking like this:

[image]

However, on a Samsung S6 Edge running Marshmallow 6.0.1, it comes up like this:

[image]

completely blank.

The `TimePickerDialog` is initialised like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Dialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(androidContext, this, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
timeDialog.setTitle("Set Appointment Time");
timeDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening but I have worked around this issue by using the solution provided by *cirit* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165328/timepickerdialog-ontimesetlistener-not-called).  He's solving a different problem but it addresses this issue too.

The solution provided by *cirit* is to put a TimePicker widget into an AlertDialog.  My implementation of his/her solution looks like this:

```
private void showTimePicker() {

    // This is implemented using an AlertDialog and a TimePicker instead of a TimePickerDialog
    // because the TimePickerDialog implementation on Samsung does not work.
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(getInternalTimestamp());

    final TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(mContext);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(mContext));
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    final AlertDialog timePickerDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // user clicked OK - store the result, perhaps by using a callback:
                    // myCallback.onTimeSet(timePicker, timePicker.getHour(), timePicker.getMinute();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setView(timePicker).show();
}
```

Not beautiful, but it works (for me) and it's not as ugly as I feared.