# Android:DatePickerdialog with Cancel button

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am working on `datepicker` dialog and one issue that i am facing is to have the cancel button on the picker(no cancel button for android jelly bean). now the problem is also with that my datepicker dialog is getting invoked on button(in `listview` adapter class) press.In adapter class i am using date_picker_id concept.. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
((Activity) LessonListViewAdapter.this.context).showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

This calls the createdialog function in `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jelly Bean DatePickerDialog --- is there a way to cancel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444238/jelly-bean-datepickerdialog-is-there-a-way-to-cancel.The) answer in the link gives you way to work around. I found this link trying to answer the one of the question regarding data picker.

Looks like it's a bug and someone else already filled it.http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34833. The answer in the link gives you way to work around.

Edit1

```
public static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
public static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 2;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

switch (id) {
case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
// set date picker as current date
myDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
break;

case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
//set time picker as current time
myDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);
break;

}

return myDialog;       
}
```

Comment: I have gone through both the links but that doesnt solve my problem.I am creating the datepicker dialog from oncreatedialog function.

Comment: protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

  switch (id) {
  case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
   
   return new DatePickerDialog(Activity.this, dateListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);

  }
  return null;
 }

Comment: Atleast you got a way to work around the cancel button issue. It should work in your case too.

Comment: can u pls post more code regarding what you have done

Comment: also use break after each case. Are you getting any errors??