# how to display datepicker in android Fragment

Tags: android, datepicker, fragment

I am using `Fragment` which is an instance of `Fragment` and not of `DialogFragment`

I am displaying form inside this fragment, and one of the field is DateField

I want to have date picker component for that field in Fragment

I did google most of the search result shows how to use `DialogFragment` to have  `DatePicker` and then use `show()` method of `Fragment`

which isn't working in my case because of type mismatch of Fragment and DialogFragment

Any example or idea would be helpful

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444238/jelly-bean-datepickerdialog-is-there-a-way-to-cancel/11493752#11493752

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use this code . I used this datepicker in my **fragment ACTIVITY**

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        DatePickerDialog dpdFromDate = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                  mDay);
        dpdFromDate.show();

        dpdFromDate.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                    //et_to_date.setText("");
                    et_from_date.setText("");
               }
            }
        });
```