# how to dismiss datepicker when the user clicks cancel button?

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker, android-dialogfragment

Cancel button is not working in my application. When i click cancel button it displays time picker dialog instead the date dialog dismiss.

```
DatePickerFragment.java
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Dialog dialog;
     private boolean mIgnoreTimeSet = false;
    public EditText activity_edittext;
    //OnDismissListener mOnDismissListener;
    public DatePickerFragment(EditText edit_text) {
        activity_edittext = edit_text;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, year, month, day);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month,
            int day) {
        Log.d("date",String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        activity_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    }

  public void onDateCancel(DatePicker view, int year, int month,int day) { 
       dialog.dismiss();        
}
}

TimePickerFragment.java
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    int  mhour,mminute;  

    public EditText activity_edittext;

    public TimePickerFragment(EditText edit_text) {
        activity_edittext = edit_text;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        mhour  = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, mhour,  mminute,false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        mhour = hourOfDay;
        mminute = minute;
        Log.d("time",String.valueOf(mhour) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(mminute));
        activity_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(mhour) + ":"
                + String.valueOf(mminute)) ;
    }
}


TimeFragment.java
public  class TimeFragment extends Fragment{    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showTimePickerDialog(new EditText(getActivity()));
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(new EditText(getActivity()));
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        NowFragment fragment = new NowFragment();

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    private void showTimePickerDialog(EditText editText) {
         TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment(new EditText(getActivity()));
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
            showDatePickerDialog(new EditText(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to remove the line "setCancelable(false);" ?

Comment: Yes i did but its still not working

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a bug with Jellybean where the Cancel button isn't working(& hence the back button). This is discussed in [Jelly Bean DatePickerDialog — is there a way to cancel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444238/jelly-bean-datepickerdialog-is-there-a-way-to-cancel/).

[David Cesarino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489607/david-cesarino), who reported the bug and workaround in the above post, posted his solution [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Q8sq_qCRv3V1NEbk5kTlJXSm8/edit?pli=1)
[Cavega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/947875/cavega) slightly modified the above solution to allow initialization of the date in the DatePickerDialog to something other than today's date.Code can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/cavega/datepickerdialogsample/src). I used his solution and got it to work.

Answer (score -1):

please remove

```
setCancelable(false);
```

and set this line instead of above line:

```
setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: I removed setCancelable(false);but it still not working.

Comment: when the user clicks cancel button it has to dismiss

Answer (score -1):

try this

> getDialog().dismiss();

Also remove

> setCancelable(false);