# Click Back button or out of the DatePicker dialog, sets the date. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

This happened with the Nexus 7 device. I have tested on Samsung devices and it's working properly. Also with the Nexus 7 device, the Cancel button is not showing at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, the trick is to provide a `null listener` to be stored as the listener, and then roll your own set of buttons [REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444238/jelly-bean-datepickerdialog-is-there-a-way-to-cancel)

```
    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(
        this,
        null, // instead of a listener
        2012, 6, 15);
    picker.setCancelable(true);
    picker.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    picker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("Picker", "Correct behavior!");
            }
        });
    picker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("Picker", "Cancel!");
            }
        });
picker.show();
```