# How to handle date picker dialog not to set in edittext when clicked outside of dialog android?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-date

When I click edittext, date picker dialog opens. without clicking done button in date picker and clicked outside of dialog, it sets in edittext.

I [checked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11444238/jelly-bean-datepickerdialog-is-there-a-way-to-cancel/12737234#12737234) but this works for first time. When selecting second time by choosing dialog and without clicking done button, it fails.

```
private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
       private boolean fired;
         public void resetFired(){
                fired = false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                if (fired) {
                    Log.e("DatePicker", "Ignoring for first time");
                    birthDayValue = selectedDay;
                    birthMonthValue = selectedMonth;
                    birthYearValue = selectedYear;
                    String birthDayDateFormt = Utils.getBirthDayDate(selectedYear,
                            selectedMonth, selectedDay);
                    dateOfBirth.setText(birthDayDateFormt);
                    dateOfBirth.setError(null);
                    return;//ignore and return.
                } 
                fired = true;//first time fired
            }
    };

};
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you calling the _resetFire()_ method on your listeners instance? Just make sure after each dissmisal you call _resetFire()_.

Comment: no. where should i use that? will you please show me a code, so that if worked i will choose and close this from unanswered question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have misunderstood the question. But I don't think this method will do what you want it to do. On that question you had a lot of good answers, try the accepted one.

Comment: i tried that and so only posted the question. however thanks. @torque203

Comment: Did you try [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Q8sq_qCRv3V1NEbk5kTlJXSm8/edit?pli=1) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        if(view.isShown()) {
            if (fired) {
                Log.e("DatePicker", "Ignoring for first time");
                birthDayValue = selectedDay;
                birthMonthValue = selectedMonth;
                birthYearValue = selectedYear;
                String birthDayDateFormt = Utils.getBirthDayDate(selectedYear,
                        selectedMonth, selectedDay);
                dateOfBirth.setText(birthDayDateFormt);
                dateOfBirth.setError(null);
                return;//ignore and return.
            } 
            fired = true;//first time fired
          }
        }
```

**if(view.isShown())** add code in this condition, 
its a simple step do it and check output