# DatePicker: Listener reacting when clicking beside the Button

Tags: java, android, datepicker, listener

My app uses a `DatePicker`. When I open the `DatePicker` and click on `Done` the date gets choosen. The problem is, that the date also gets choosen, if the user clicks besides the `DatePicker`. See here:

[image]

The `Listener` should only react if the `Done Button` is clicked. But it also reacts if the surrounding (red) of the `DatePicker` is clicked.

**My Question:**
How do I prevent this?

If you want to see some code, pls leave a comment.

**I already tried this:**  [How to handle date picker dialog not to set in edittext when clicked outside of dialog android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262439/how-to-handle-date-picker-dialog-not-to-set-in-edittext-when-clicked-outside-of)

```
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        //DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
        mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            private boolean fired;
            public void resetFired(){
                fired = false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                if(view.isShown()){
                    if(fired){
                        setDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        //ListView erneuern
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        return;
                    }
                    fired = true;
                }
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        mDatePicker.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        mDatePicker.setTitle("Wähle ein Datum");
        mDatePicker.show();
```

But it does not work correctly. The click on the background bug gets solved. But now the `Done Button` stops working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262439/how-to-handle-date-picker-dialog-not-to-set-in-edittext-when-clicked-outside-of

Comment: I tried it, but it dint work. See my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple dialog containing an DatePicker. 
So You can set to no-cancelable.

using setCancelable API

.setCancelable(false);

[Dialog reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog)